# While trying to implement CameraX, the app crashes

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera2, android-camerax

I was trying to make a simple CameraX app. I'm uploading the github link for my app:
https://github.com/srivastavapoorv/GithubPracticeAndroid/tree/master/CameraX

When I try to run it, the app crashes
And AndroidStudio gives this error in logcat:
https://i2.paste.pics/c77714ec26373276884c6d490f3bbe40.png

This is AndroidManifest.xml
`

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.CameraX">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

`

build.gradle(app)

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

}

android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.camerax"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
```

}

dependencies {

```
def camerax_version = "1.0.0-alpha06"

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

//noinspection GradleDependency
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:$camerax_version"
//noinspection GradleDependency
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$camerax_version"
```

}

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: Please add this textureview = findViewById(R.id.textureview) as TextureView after setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

Comment: @Hascher Thanks, It worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code where you're getting the crash

```
preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener {
    val parent = textureView.parent as ViewGroup
    parent.removeView(textureView)
    // crash on next line, "cannot add a null child view to a ViewGroup"
    parent.addView(textureView, 0)
    textureView.setSurfaceTexture(it.surfaceTexture)
}
```

so it's saying that `textureView` is null, but you just called `textureView.parent` and `removeView(textureView)` with no crashes, so it must have become null after the `removeView` call.

You're using synthetic imports (the `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*` line) which is creating that `textureView` reference from your layout file - I don't know exactly how it handles caching things, but at a guess, calling `removeView` (which removes the view from the layout) causes the synthetic stuff to lose/drop its reference to that view object. So the value becomes null, and you've lost it.

Synthetics is deprecated, but you can probably fix this by just grabbing your own explicit reference to that view. You could use `findViewById` or just grab a reference from the synthetic variable:

```
// top-level variable - you need to grab and keep a reference before it gets lost
val preciousTextureView: TextureView = findViewById(R.id.textureView)
// or
val preciousTextureView: TextureView = textureView
```

the first one will definitely work, the second one *should*. Then you just use `preciousTextureView` instead of `textureView` in your code